# While solving LDE can the IF $e^{\int \frac{dx}{x}}$ be taken as x instead of |x|?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

While solving the differential equation 
$x\frac {dy}{dx}+y-x+ xy\cot{x}=0\;for\;x\neq 0$, I noticed in the attached solution, the omission of the absolute value symbol around the integration factor $x\sin{x}$. To me it appeared as if half the solution set is ignored by the attached solution where $x\sin{x}<0$. However I need some experts' opinion and to be sure if my worries are uncalled for.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No solution is lost here. It suffices to find ONE integrating factor. So $x\sin(x)$ is enough. Nothing changes if we take  $-x\sin(x)$ or $Cx\sin(x)$ with real $C\not=0.$ Indeed after multiplying both sides of the linear ODE by $Cx\sin(x)$ we have
$$Cx\sin(x)\left(\frac {dy}{dx}+y(x)\left(\frac{1}{x}+\cot(x)\right)\right)=Cx\sin(x)$$
that is
$$C\frac {d}{dx}\left(x\sin(x)y(x)\right)=Cx\sin(x)$$
As you can see the value of the constant $C\not =0$ is irrelevant.